# How to print object data from OrderedCollection in Smalltalk

Tags: loops, smalltalk

I have a class in Smalltalk that stores an OrderedCollection of objects. Each object has a name. I would like to iterate over the OrderedCollection objects and print out the name of each of these objects. For example, in Java I would have something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  System.out.println(array[i].getName());
}
```

This is how far I got in Smalltalk, where "list" is the OrderedCollection:

```
1 to: list size do: [
:x | Transcript show: 'The object name:' list at: x printString; cr.
]
```

Comment: `list do: [:object | Transcript show: 'The object name: ' , object name; cr]`

Comment: In Java, to enumerate an array `foo`, you'd more compactly write, `for ( int i: foo ) { ... }` which a little more closely mirrors the right way to do it in Smalltalk, `foo do: [ :each | ... ]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution is good, except for two small mistakes: (1) you forgot some parenthesis and (2) the concatenation message `#,` is missing:

```
1 to: list size do: [
   :x | Transcript show: 'The object name:' list at: x printString; cr.
]
```

should have been

```
1 to: list size do: [
   :x | Transcript show: 'The object name:' , (list at: x) printString; cr.
]
```

otherwise the `Transcript` object would receive the message `#show:at:`, which it doesn't understand. Also, you have to concatenate the string `'The object name: '` with `(list at: x) printString`, and that's why you need the concatenation message `#,` in between.

Note however that in your example there is no need to use indexes. Instead of iterating from `1` to `list size` you could simply enumerate the objects in the `list` collection, like this:

```
list do: [:object | Transcript show: 'The object name: ' , object printString; cr]
```

This form is usually preferred because it avoids the use of an intermediate index (`x` in your example) and forces you to access the `x-`th element of the collection using `#at:`, all of which makes your code easier to read and modify.

Comment: +1, though I would also add that it is very typical in Smalltalk for the iteration variable to be called `each`, or `eachSomething` as appropriate, to emphasise its iterative nature, and that we are doing something for _each_ value in the list. To be even more pedantic, I would try not to call your collection `list`, because it ties you to a certain collection implementation. (What if you need it to be a `Set` later on?) Instead, I'd recommend the OP use a pluralised noun, say, `accounts`, or `objects`, or whatever applies in your domain.

Comment: Good point @AmosM.Carpenter. Generic names like `list`, `collection` and the like are only appropriate when the context makes their meaning apparent (e.g., the ivar `collection` of `PositionableStream` in Pharo.) Otherwise it is more intention revealing to use a specific noun for the elements the assortment contains. Because of this very same reason, I normally don't use `each` for the generic enumeration variable and say instead `accounts do: [:account | <blah>]`. It is anyway always valuable to help people learn folkloric conventions.

Comment: Get the best of both worlds, and use `accounts do: [:eachAccount | <blah>]`. Never hurts to be explicit, and if someone looks at a line of code that is nested a couple of levels deep, without having to look at the context, they'll know at a glance that `eachAccount` is the iteration variable, while `account` could be an instance variable or a temp. There's a good reason for that convention. :-)